# How can I create relative URL in my MDX file?

Tags: markdown

Let's say I'm on `/science/natural` page. This URL serves the `/science/natural/index.mdx`.

In that file, I want to create a menu. This is my markup:

```
﻿# Natural Sciences

- [Anatomy & Physiology](anatomy-and-physiology)
- [Astronomy](astronomy)
- [Biochemistry](biochemistry)
- [Biology](biology)
- [Botany](botany)
- [Chemistry](chemistry)
- [Classical physics](classical-physics)
- [Embryology](embryology)
- [Geography](geography)
- [Geology](geology)
- [Immunology](immunology)
- [Microbiology](microbiology)
- [Modern physics](modern-physics)
- [Mycology](mycology)
- [Neurology](neurology)
- [Organic chemistry](organic-chemistry)
- [Particle physics](particle-physics)
- [Quantum physics](quantum-physics)
- [Zoology](zoology)
```

I would expect the links to be appended to the current path. In other words, I would expect the path for `Biology` become `/science/natural/biology`. But it becomes `/science/biology`.

I tried to change the links to `[Biology](./biology)` but that did not make it work.

How can I achieve that?